# How can I make a subcaptionbox label appear in front of an image?

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats, formatting, subcaption

This MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,size=Large,position=top, skip=-10pt, justification=raggedright, singlelinecheck=false]{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-b}}

  \caption{Some caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Produces the following output:

[image]

In which the labels (a) and (b) are being occluded due to the "skip" option to subcaption. I really want the label to be more to the right than the default, but I do not know how to make subcaption put the label in front of the image. Moreover, I do not understand why the text is placed behind the image in the first place.

**How can I put the labels (a) and (b) in front of the text?** There does not seem to be any option in caption controlling the "depth" of things. 
My endgame is to have a figure as in the image above but with the text in front for each sub figure. The caption must be there where it is now as well.

BTW, the `documentclass` I have to use (`achemso`) wont let me use `floatrow`.

Comment: Probably related: [Overlay subfigure caption with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187103/134144)

Answer (score 2):

I got around it using the accepted answer here:

[Put subfigure labels inside figures using subfig package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128844/put-subfigure-labels-inside-figures-using-subfig-package)

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\subfigimg}[3][,]{%
  \setbox1=\hbox{\includegraphics[#1]{#3}}% Store image in box
  \leavevmode\rlap{\usebox1}% Print image
  \rlap{\hspace*{10pt}\raisebox{\dimexpr\ht1-1.2\baselineskip}{\large\textbf{#2}}}% Print label
  \phantom{\usebox1}% Insert appropriate spcing
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.5\linewidth}@{\quad}p{0.5\linewidth}@{}}
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{A)}{example-image-a} \\
    \subfigimg[width=\linewidth]{B)}{example-image-b} 
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the desired output:
[image]

However this feels kind of hacky and I still neither know how to do it with subcaption nor understand why the text is placed behind the image there. So if anyone knows I will accept the answer.